# Create .zip with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to zip files. My problem is that I want to have also the root directory but only include *.pdf documents. I just found solutions to compress the full root directory or only pdfs without the root directory. Here an example: myFolder {name1.pdf,name1.xml,name2.pdf,name2.xml} and I want my zip to look like: result.zip{myFolder{name1.pdf,name2.pdf}.
Following doesn't work because it excludes the root directory:

```
Compress-Archive -Update -Path ${PWD}\myFolder\*.pdf -DestinationPath ${PWD}\result.zip
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done as a two-step process:

1. [Call RoboCopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472692/how-to-copy-a-directory-structure-but-only-include-certain-files-using-windows) through [PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/questions/129098/how-to-get-robocopy-running-in-powershell) to copy the directory structure and files of a specific extension [`/E` argument copies empty folders, too, if needed]:

   ```
   ROBOCOPY C:\Source C:\Destination data.zip info.txt /E
   ```
2. Now call *Compress-Archive* to compress `C:\Destination`.